# Virtual Host with xampp link creation problem

Tags: laravel, composer-php

I installed laravel 6.0 through composer and tried to create own link as blog.laravel.com by changing vhosts file as

DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs"
ServerName localhost

[image: Error]

DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/blog/public"
ServerName blog.laravel.com

and  C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\host file as

127.0.0.1 localhost
127.0.0.1 blog.laravel.com

but now instead of showing blog.laravel.com page my browser redirecting me to https://blog.laravel.com/dashboard/ page

What should I do?

Comment: Well, does your code have something that'd redirect to `dashboard`?

Comment: Which code I haven't written anything yet

Comment: Well, *something* is doing the redirect, presumably.

Comment: What could it possibly be?

Answer (score -1):

first, you should check xampp status.

then, you can try: http://blog.laravel.com/

not https